# Distance Between Non Parallel Segments

Tags: geometry, estimation

Suppose we have two rulers $\mathcal{L}_1$ and $\mathcal{L}_2$ -i.e. sets of parallel segments, separated by a unity distance-. Each segment is linked to an integer number $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

We can easily measure the distance when both rules are parallel, by taking the distance between the zeros -depicted as red segments-.

One ruler suffer an (small) angular deviation, but I am still forced to calculate an estimate of that distance. How should I calculate or redefine that distance?.

In the parallel case, the distance is the length of the smallest projection following a perpendicular direction.

In the angular deviated case, the distance could be the length of some projection following the green lines directions. But this is only an intuitive guess without any support or justification.

[image]

Comment: With what information do you define the rulers? There are several different ways of representing such a set of line segments, each of which lends itself to a different method of computing distance. Also, would it be possible to be a bit more precise about what you mean by "distance"? I presume you're asking for the minimum distance between two specified segments, one from each ruler.

Comment: Lets assume the rules are built such as the distance between the segments is 1x and the length of the segments is 30x, and they overlap at 50%,  The rules should "match" when the parallel distance is zero, the overlap is 100% and the angle is zero.

Comment: @hyprfrco: You didn't really answer Kajelad's clarifying question about what you mean by "distance". It is also not clear what your figure of 50% is supposed to measure.

Comment: It looks like the left side of the distance is the red line in the vertical set.  What part of the red line in the inclined set is the right side of the distance?

Comment: I am not clear on which is the definition of the distance in this case. I don't know how to define it, obtain it, or estimate it. If i figure it out i can easily program it and solve the question.

Comment: If the rulers are parallel the case is obvious. But if i have an angle, although little, i dont have a clear answer for how to obtain a proper distance.

Comment: In terms of representation, would it be possible to write these objects as something similar to $\{\vec x\in\mathbb R^2:\vec x\cdot\hat n = m\in\mathbb Z\}$? ALso, if you don't have a definition for distance, whould it be possible to provide some context in order to understand what precisely you're trying to compute?

Comment: Sure, these are two measurement rules for capture displacements through image processing. But the rules are not parallel in practice. Hence we can assume they are rules (the distance between graduations is parallel and constant), and there exist an angle between them. So we have the rules, and the angle, but we lost the definition of distance. Indeed each segment have center $\vec c_i+m \hat n_i, i=1,2, m \in \mathbb{Z}$. The length of the segments don't seems to be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best interpretation is taking the intersection of the rulers directions as reference:

$$
d=x_2\cdot v_2-x_1\cdot v_1
$$

A tempting interpretation is to measure through a direction:

$$
d(v)=(x_2-x_1)\cdot v
$$

where $x_i$ are the centers and $v_i$ the unitary directions of each rule $\mathbf L_i$.

A special case is taking $v$ as the **bisector** of the directions $v_i$:

$$v=\frac{v_1+v_2}{|v_1+v_2|}$$

This solution gets undefined when $v_i$ are opposite directions.

For both cases, the center $x_j$ being farther from the intersection of the rulers directions $v_j$ will have the longest distance (projection), i.e. the distance $d(v_j)$ will be greater for that ruler.

Answer (score 1):

Write $\mathcal{S}_i$ for the zero segment of $\mathcal{L}_i$
Let $A_i,B_i$ be the extremities of $\mathcal{S}_i$ : $\mathcal{S}_i = [A_i,B_i]$.

Write $\mathcal{D}_i$ for the line supporting the zero segment of $\mathcal{L}_i$ (hence, $\mathcal{D}_i =(A_i,B_i))$.

If $\mathcal{S}_1$ and $\mathcal{S}_2$ intersect, $d(\mathcal{S}_1,\mathcal{S}_2)=0$.

**lemma**(proof is left to you) If $\mathcal{S}_1 \cap \mathcal{S}_2 \neq \emptyset$, then (at least) one of the following cases must hold :

1. There is $X \in \mathcal{S}_2$ such that $d(\mathcal{S}_1,\mathcal{S}_2)=d(A_1,X)$
2. There is $X \in \mathcal{S}_2$ such that $d(\mathcal{S}_1,\mathcal{S}_2)=d(B_1,X)$
3. There is $X \in \mathcal{S}_1$ such that $d(\mathcal{S}_1,\mathcal{S}_2)=d(A_2,X)$
4. There is $X \in \mathcal{S}_1$ such that $d(\mathcal{S}_1,\mathcal{S}_2)=d(B_2,X)$

Now there are many cases. Consider the strips 
$$strip(\mathcal{S}_i) :=\{P | \exists X \in \mathcal{S}_i, (XP)\perp \mathcal{S}_i \}$$

*Either* no endpoint of $\mathcal{S}_1$ belongs to $strip(\mathcal{S}_2)$ and no endpoint of $\mathcal{S}_2$ belongs to $strip(\mathcal{S}_1)$, then  $$d(\mathcal{S}_1,\mathcal{S}_2) = min\big(d(A_1,A_2),d(A_1,B_2), d(B_1, A_2),d(B_1,B_2)\big)$$
  *Otherwise*, there are 4 possibilities for $d(\mathcal{S}_1,\mathcal{S}_2)$, which can now be computed using [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) :

- $d(\mathcal{S}_1,\mathcal{S}_2) = d(A_1,\mathcal{D}_2)$
- $d(\mathcal{S}_1,\mathcal{S}_2) = d(B_1,\mathcal{D}_2)$
- $d(\mathcal{S}_1,\mathcal{S}_2) = d(A_2,\mathcal{D}_1)$
- $d(\mathcal{S}_1,\mathcal{S}_2) = d(B_2,\mathcal{D}_1)$

**Edit**
The hidden argument above is that 
$$C \in strip([AB]) \Rightarrow d(C,[AB]) = d(C,(AB))$$
$$C \notin strip([AB]) \Rightarrow d(C,[AB]) = \operatorname{min}(d(C,A),d(C,B))$$

Comment: How should I measure or define the distance between two segments? I am clear between a point and a line, but between segments?. Should i project into the green lines? Is that the best option one could figure? Or just an intuition without any support?

Comment: @Brethlosze : the distance between two non-empty sets X and Y is defined as $$d(X,Y) = \operatorname{min}_{x,y \in X \times Y} d(x,y)$$

Comment: Suppose you have two rulers and you want to measure $d$. In the parallel case, this is trivial: the smallest perpendicular path between the parallel lines. Suppose one of these rulers suffer a small angular deviation, but I am still forced to bring an estimate. How should I define that distance?. I am guessing this should be some kind of projection into the green lines at the median points, or something like that. I am asking for a better guess.

Comment: Forget about the green lines. In the picture you posted, the distance between the vertical red line and the other red line is the length of a segment that is **perpendicular** to one of the red lines.